# Always use mono-space font for Chrome input fields

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to force Google Chrome to always use a mono-spaced font for input fields, no matter what an arbitrary site's (broken) style sheet tells Chrome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**nb: this answer is now redundant as Chrome has removed support for user style sheets. I'd suggest dear reader to refer to the other answer, although I haven't tested it myself.**

You could add a rule along the lines of

```
textarea { font-family: monospace !important; }
```

to your user stylesheet.

I found [this post](http://ednortonengineeringsociety.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/better-living-through-user-stylesheets.html) explaining where to find that file on common operating systems:

> For Chrome, you need to find the Custom.css file. On Windows
>   Vista/7/2008, it is located at the following (replace 
>   with, ahem, your user id):
>
> ```
> C:\Users\<your-userid>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\
> ```
>
> [Presumably on Windows XP it will be under C:\Documents and
>   Settings\ in a similar location.]
>
> For Mac OS X, it is at:
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/
> ```
>
> On Ubuntu Linux it is found here:
>
> ```
> ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/User StyleSheets
> ```

Comment: Support for user style sheets in Chrome [was removed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347016).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Stylish add-on (for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en)), which enables you to specify custom CSS stylesheets for any website.

To make all pages use monospace fonts:

- Install Stylish
- Click the Stylish icon
- Click “Create New Style”
- Paste the code `textarea { font-family: monospace !important; }`
- At the bottom of the screen, set to which URLs it should apply
- Click “Save” on the left

If you want a global style that applies to *all* websites, you should include the code

```
/* i really want this to be global */
```

in your stylesheet, per the [Stylish help](https://github.com/stylish-userstyles/stylish/wiki/Preventing-global-styles).

Answer (score 0):

The previous solutions are no longer valid; user style sheet support was removed from Chrome, and [Stylish is no longer available](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/07/stylish-extension-with-2m-downloads-banished-for-tracking-every-site-visit/). There is a new extension which can be used:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne/related

Seems to work similarly to Stylish.